# What HTML helper do I use to create a simple dropdownlist that doesn't take in any variables?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I want to have a simple select->option dropdown list that I am not passing any (SelectItem collection) values to.  I already know the values so I don't need to do all that (they are static).

Need to do something like so:

```
<select id="day" name="day">
  <option value="1">Sunday</option>
  <option value="2">Monday</option>
</select>

<select id="hour" name="hour">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

All examples seem to show how to create a IEnum passing it in via the ViewData.  This is in a partial, and I don't want to be sending in this data, I just want it to show up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a select list with either a List of strings or a Dictionary of items (if you want different id's and values) inside your drop down list to define your values.

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("day", new SelectList(
    new Dictionary<int,string> { { 1, "Sunday" }, { 2, "Monday" } },
    "Key", "Value"))
%>

<%= Html.DropDownList("hour", new SelectList(
    new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", "4" }))
%>
```

Comment: For some reason SelectList and the System.Web.Mvc namespace doesn't show up under intellesense.  I'll have to give it a try and see if it's just an intellesense problem or if that'll work.  For some stupid reason I just assumed that that wouldn't work.

Comment: Sometimes intellisense for me stops working but can't help you there. Also, as jfar said, if you have static values just use HTML instead of a helper.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the state of the drop downs without using a helper?

Comment: Great answer, would it be nicer if you added how to have a empty option as default.

Comment: That is what Intellisense is for in Visual Studio! Also the question does not ask for an empty option so was not required for this question.

Answer (score 0):

If they are static keep them as HTML.  No sense complicating things.

Comment: Problem is when you have validation on a form, when you return to the form after an error, the state of the drop downs are lost.  With helpers they remain.

Comment: Ok, sounded like you didn't need any ModelState info.

Comment: I don't want to have to pass the drop down values themselves in, but I do want the state of the boxes to remain after a round trip.