# ASP.NET MVC Html.Dropdown - setting the default value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Yesterday I asked the following question [Html.Dropdown - get the the value of each option to be the same as the text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564372/html-dropdown-get-the-the-value-of-each-option-to-be-the-same-as-the-text) which was answered when I found the following post [What HTML helper do I use to create a simple dropdownlist that doesn't take in any variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821585/what-html-helper-do-i-use-to-create-a-simple-dropdownlist-that-doesnt-take-in-an)
now that's all well and good however, how would I select a default value (like monthly), here's my code...

```
<%: Html.DropDownList("day", new SelectList(
    new Dictionary<string,string> { { "Weekly", "Weekly" }, { "Monthly", "Monthly" }, { "Quarterly", "Quarterly" }, { "Annually", "Annually" } },
    "Key", "Value"))
%>
```

Any help would be appreciated as I haven't found an example to explain this rather simple requirement, perhaps I should purchase a book on MVC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492553.aspx) overload

> ```
>     public SelectList(IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField, object selectedValue);
> ```

The last parameter is selected value. You could rewrite your method as

```
 <%: Html.DropDownList("day", new
 SelectList(
     new Dictionary<string,string> { { "Weekly", "Weekly" }, { "Monthly",
 "Monthly" }, { "Quarterly",
 "Quarterly" }, { "Annually",
 "Annually" } },
     "Key", "Value", "Monthly")) %>
```